# Hide PopupMenu with Copy option from Google Translate overlay?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-translate

I'm experimenting with in-app translations and launching a Google Translate overlay as explained in this Android blog post: [In-app translations in Android Marshmallow](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/10/in-app-translations-in-android.html).

As a basic example (which assumes the Translate app is installed), this involves firing off an intent like this:

```
String text = "Dorothy lived...";
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.translate");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT, text);
startActivity(intent);
```

This is working fine; however, unlike the screenshots shown in the blog post, the actual Google Translate overlay has a PopupMenu that includes a Copy option for the translated result.  Is there a way to suppress this PopupMenu? You can easily set the original and target languages to the same language and use this feature to copy the entire original text. I want to provide the ability to translate a word or paragraph while protecting the original content from Copy/Paste.

I suppose I could do this with the Google Translate API but triggering the Google Translate app with an intent is so simple. Perhaps there is an Extra value that might result in a more basic overlay?

[image]

Comment: any thing you got yet? i need same for my app

Comment: Unfortunately not.  For the moment I'm monitoring the selected text and limiting it to a few hundred characters.  It's enough to translate a sentence or two while protecting the content from massive copy/paste.

Comment: google want $$ from us it mean :) , is there any why to getIntentExtra or intent result , i think not , what you say?